# ImportError: cannot import name 'Gui' from 'taipy

Tags: python, taipy

Why I can't use Gui from taipy module but I have installed the taipy module sucessfully.

taipy.py:

```
from taipy import Gui

page = """

# Hello World  with *Taipy*This is my first Taipy test app.
And it is running fine!

 

Gui(page).run(use_reloader=True)  # use_reloader=True if you are in development
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Arin-Chaudhary\Taipy\basic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from taipy import Gui
ImportError: cannot import name 'Gui' from 'taipy' (C:\Users\rk157\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\taipy\__init__.py)
```

I want to find the answer of this question.

Comment: Can you check if taipy is correctly installed, run pip freeze.

Comment: In your example, your string is never closed. You should have 3 double quotes to close the string.

If this does not fix your problem, please provide the Python and Taipy versions so we can try to reproduce the issue. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already commented, can you check which version of Taipy you are using using `pip list` in a terminal. You could also re-install taipy on a new environment.

You can also try:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
```

Let me know if this helps